# R3InjectorError for missing service despite resolving in a different scope

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Running into an R3InjectorError for a missing dependency. Here is the setup:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
  constructor(
    @Inject(ServiceBInjectionToken) private readonly IServiceB
  ) { }
}
```

```js
export class MainService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(ServiceBInjectionToken) private readonly IServiceB,
    private readonly IServiceA
  ) { }
}
```

Module:

```
@NgModule(
  providers: [
    ServiceA,
    { provide: ServiceBInjectionToken, useExisting: ServiceB }
  ]
)
```

There's some Angular DI hierarchy thing going on that I don't understand, because at runtime within `MainService`, `ServiceB` definitely exists, and the R3InjectorError isn't about not being able to find `ServiceA`, it's about not being able to give `ServiceA` an `IServiceB`. In the module do I need to specify that `ServiceA` also gets `ServiceB` somehow?

Comment: Could you please share code with decorators for ServiceBInjectionToken, ServiceB and MainService?